# What is the benefit of using django.conf.urls.patterns versus a list of url in Django

Tags: python, django, url

Are there benefits for using `django.conf.urls.patterns` versus just a list of url?

For example what is the difference between

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

vs

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)))
```

Comment: It's explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a list because *patterns()* is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.patterns) since version 1.8, and will be removed in 1.10:

```
def patterns(prefix, *args):
    warnings.warn(
        'django.conf.urls.patterns() is deprecated and will be removed in '
        'Django 1.10. Update your urlpatterns to be a list of '
        'django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.',
        RemovedInDjango110Warning, stacklevel=2
    )
```

Comment: No they're not, they are still in 1.8. Your own (Leistungsabfall's) link even says that

Comment: @Sayse Your comment isn't true. deprecated != removed

Comment: @Sayse what are you talking about? They are there, but they are deprecated, as the link says. That means you should no longer use them in new projects.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - "For these reasons, we are deprecating it", from Leistungsabfall's link. So they will be deprecated, but they aren't yet.

Comment: @Sayse "deprecated" - means that it should be avoided, but it isn't removed due to downward compatiblity